# Mostrar ProgressBar durante ejecucion de registrar respuestas en kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Ya eh logrado registrar mis respuestas a mi base de datos SQL, pero cuando doy clic en guardar esto demora porque se ejecuta 1 bucle donde recorre las respuestas de mi recycleview y esto hace que se demore hasta se bloquea el activity hasta terminar el proceso.

Para evitar esto, estoy intentando mostrar 1 progressBar al iniciar y al terminar el proceso de registro.

Este es mi Clase **listapreuso** donde se muestra el **recycleview** con las preguntas y donde esta el onOptionsItemSelected que ejecuta el codigo para guardar las respuestas.

```
private fun mirecycle(){
  binding.recycleviewpreguntas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
  binding.recycleviewpreguntas.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
  listado = sp.listarpreguntas(Conexiones.listarpreguntas)
  binding.recycleviewpreguntas.adapter =preusoadapter(this,listado)
```

}

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    var itemview = item.itemId

    var id : String
    var vsi : String = ""
    var vno : String = ""
    var vna : String = ""
    var viss : String = ""
    var vdss : String = ""
    var vfm: String = ""
    var vfs : String = ""
    val modelo : String = Build.MODEL
    val version : String = Build.DEVICE
    val marca : String = Build.MANUFACTURER

    if (itemview == R.id.listopedido) {
        for  (posicion in listado.indices){
            id =  listado.get(posicion).id_pregunta
            vsi = listado.get(posicion).valorsi
            vno = listado.get(posicion).valorno
            vna = listado.get(posicion).valorna
            viss = listado.get(posicion).valorivss
            vdss = listado.get(posicion).valordss
            vfm = listado.get(posicion).valorfm
            vfs = listado.get(posicion).valorfs

            sr.registrarespuestas(Conexiones.registrarpreguntas,idpersonal,codvehiculo,id,vsi,vno,vna,viss,vdss,vfm,vfs,"prueba","prueba",marca,version,modelo)

            Toast.makeText(this@listapreuso, "Registro Preguntas Exitoso!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

        }
        listado.clear()
        //recyclerpedidoView.removeAllViewsInLayout()

    }
    return false
}
```

No logro donde insertar el ProgressBar tengo el siguiente codigo que me muestra el progressBar.

```
lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog
progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Espere Por favor,Registrando Respuestas!")
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Registrando...")
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false) // blocks UI interaction
                    progressDialog.show()
```

Alguna Idea en donde puedo colocar el progressBar ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes dos problemas que debes resolver por separado.

Primero: Tu app nunca debe bloquear el hilo principal, todas las operaciones que tomen mucho tiempo se deben hacer en un hilo de background, para eso puedes usar [coroutinas de Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) que es lo más fácil de entender (Lo mejor es usar [MVVM con los ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) de jetpack).

Segundo: Mostrar diálogos de "loading" no es buena práctica, te sale mejor mostrar un [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) ya que este sigue la animación sin bloquear el fragmento/activity.

Comment: Evita dejar comentarios en la zonas de respuesta, espera a que tengas la reputación necesaria para poder comentar, date una vuelta en [¿Cómo escribir una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: AKoch, es cierto justo estoy investigando las corrutinas para no consumir el hilo principal, sobre MVVM aun estoy lejos de eso, creo yo con las currutinas y un progressbar seria suficiente, gracias por tu tiempo .